# Replacing whitespace in a string with .replace

Tags: jquery, string, replace

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.shoppingBasket tr').each(function() {
            var pName = $(this).find("span.pastorder-productname").text().trim().match(/\w*\s\X\d/g);

            if (pName != null) {
                var pQuantity = $(this).find("td.cart-quantity").text().trim();
                pName = pName.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                console.log(pName);

            }  
        });
    });
```

I have this little piece of code to loop through all the items that are listed in the receipt and grab their name (often the product name has extra stuff around it, and I only wanted the product name which is "Something XY". I know this is working correctly as if I print out pName it's what I expect.

However, we found out some methods we are using don't like having a space in the name, so my aim was to use the .replace method to remove the space in the middle of the string.

I tried using:

```
            var pName = $(this).find("span.pastorder-productname").text().trim().match(/\w*\s\X\d/g).replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

But I got the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

After that I have tried adding it inside the loop and having:

```
            if (pName != null) {
                var pQuantity = $(this).find("td.cart-quantity").text().trim();
                pName = pName.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                console.log(pName);

            }
```

But I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null`

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something silly but I'm not sure what, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't leave the original `.replace()` call somewhere outside of the `if`-block? As your example stands, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Also: what are you trying to match with your regex? `\X` is the same as just `X` matching the character 'X' in js-regex.

Comment: I tried to post the solution, but I couldn't format it apparently so I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working for me using:

```
            var pName = $(this).find("span.pastorder-productname").text().trim().replace(/\s+/g, '').match(/\w*\X\d/g);
```

That appears to be giving me the result I'm aiming for.

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
if(pName!==null){
    pName = pName.text().replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

Comment: Using !== instead of != will actually evaluate to true if pName is undefined, so it will cause another problem if it ever is undefined.

Comment: @eicto You are correct, but that wasn't the point. The point was that changing != to !== doesn't add any benefit to OP and it opens up for a different problem if pName ever would be `undefined`.